# Hard time understanding Async operations with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am working on a small Node application that is a simple listener for a few SQS queues and once messages are received, the code will take those objects, parse them and then insert them into DynamoDB.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var config = require('./config/config'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sqsQueueURLs = config.sqs.urls,
    _ = require('underscore'),
    sqs = require('./lib/sqs'),
    dynamo = require('./lib/mildsaucedb'),
    async = require('async'),
    tasks = [];

config.sqs.queues.forEach(function(element, index) {
    tasks.push((function(callback) {
        var key = element.split("-").pop(),
            tableName = config.dynamo[key],
            params = {
                QueueUrl: config.sqs.urls[key],
                VisibilityTimeout: 60
            };

        sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err) console.log(err);

            if(data.Messages) {
                var message = data.Messages[0],
                    body    = JSON.parse(message.Body);

                dynamo.init(key, body, tableName);
                callback();
            }
        });
    }));
});

async.parallel(tasks, function(err, results) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

DynamoDb.js

```
"use strict";

var AWS = require('./aws'),
    DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB(),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    errors = [], tblName;

var createActivity = function (obj) {
    DynamoDB.putItem({
        "TableName": tblName,
        "Item": {
            "UserId": { "N": obj.user_id.toString() },
            "CampaignId": { "N": obj.campaign_id.toString() },
            "Email": { "S": obj.email },
            "CustomActivityNodeId": { "N": obj.custom_activity_node_id.toString() }
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            errors.push(err);
        }
    });
};

var createAuthentication = function (obj) {
    DynamoDB.putItem({
        "TableName": tblName,
        "Item": {
            "UserId": { "N": obj.user_id.toString() },
            "CampaignId": { "N": obj.campaign_id.toString() },
            "Provider": { "S": obj.provider },
            "UID": { "S": obj.uid },
            "OauthToken": { "S": obj.oauth_token },
            "OauthTokenSecret": { "S": obj.oauth_token_secret },
            "Nickname": { "S": obj.nickname }
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            errors.push(err);
        }
    });
};

var createUser = function(obj) {

    if(_.has(obj, "authentication")) {
        createAuthentication(obj.authentication);
    }

    DynamoDB.putItem({
        "TableName": tblName,
        "Item": {
            "UserId": { "N": obj.user_id.toString() },
            "Identifier": { "S": obj.identifier },
            "ReferralToken": { "S": obj.referral_token },
            "CampaignId": { "N": obj.campaign_id.toString() },
            "FirstName": { "S": obj.first_name },
            "LastName": { "S": obj.last_name },
            "Gender": { "S": obj.gender },
            "BirthDate": { "S": obj.birthdate },
            "Username": { "S": obj.username },
            "MobileNumber": { "S": obj.mobile_number },
            "PostalCodeText": { "S": obj.postal_code_text },
            "Classification": { "S": obj.classification },
            "DeliveryEmail": { "B": obj.delivery_email },
            "DeliverySMS": { "B": obj.delivery_sms }
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            errors.push(err);
        }
    });
};

var dbMap = {
    'users': createUser,
    'activities': createActivity,
    'authentications': createAuthentication
};

var processErrors = function() {
    if(!_.isEmpty(errors)) {
        console.log(errors);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    init: function(qType, qObj, tableName) {

        if(_.isEmpty(qObj)) {
            errors.push("Object to insert is empty");
            return;
        }

        tblName = tableName;

        dbMap[qType](qObj);
        processErrors();
    }
}
```

But I can't get consistent results. It seems as though the script "pick and chooses" which queue it hits instead of hitting each one at separate times.

Comment: shouldn't you be executing `callback` after the asynchronous action completes rather than after you call it?

Comment: @KevinB - That's also something I am in the "dark" about. I don't fully understand how `callback` works. Can you show an example?

Comment: the best example would be your own. move `callback()` up 3 lines, into the callback of the async action.

Comment: @KevinB I updated my answer with the moved `callback()` method. I'm still getting inconsistent results

Comment: is `if(data.Messages) {` ever false? is `dynamo.init(` asynchronous?

Comment: @KevinB `data.Messages` could be blank and I updated my question to include the `dynamo.init` method call

Comment: the code you added is riddled with the same kind of errors. For example, `processErrors();` will never find any db errors because it executes before any db actions take place.

Comment: Gotcha. I suppose I need to look into making my code asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, each of those asynchronous db actions need to be able to accept a callback, you can then use that callback to ensure that the code runs in the correct order.

Comment: You will of course notice that you're getting into what some call "callback hell". you can begin to reign it all back in using modules such as async and promise.

Comment: Makes sense. Let me see about cleaning up the code and then I am sure to have more questions. Thanks for taking a look! Do you have any suggestions off the top of your head with the code I have posted?

Comment: The biggest thing you need is each of the methods that interact with the database need their own callback, dynamo.init needs a callback, and when the method that interact with the database's callback is executed, you would then need to execute the callback passed to dynamo.init so that your task running will know to execute the callback of async. :) so many callbacks.

Comment: @KevinB would using something like `EventEmitter` in Node help with working with these async operations? http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/

Comment: I've never tried, just doesn't seem like the right tool in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

SQS does not guarantee FIFO. You may be running into issues there. 
http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/